# regexp to get second matching item

Tags: php, regex

I have the following content (as an example):

```
[gallery ids="1955,1947,1951,1945,1953,1949"]
```

I have to find **first id** in ids array. I could do this using the following regexp:

```
 $pattern = '~\[gallery.+ids="\K([^,]*)~';
```

However, now I also need to get exactly **second id**, unfourtunately i am not able to construct regexp for this.

Comment: Isn't is easier to grab the whole `ids` value and explode it to access the IDs? Use `'~\[gallery[^][]+\bids="([^"]*)~'` and then explode `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will return the first and second id:

```
$pattern = '~\[gallery.+ids="\K(\d*),(\d*)~';
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I described in my comment:

```
$s = '[gallery ids="1955,1947,1951,1945,1953,1949"]';
preg_match_all('~\[gallery[^][]+\bids="([^"]+)~', $s, $ids);
$ids_arr = explode(",", $ids[1][0]);
print_r($ids_arr);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/245oP5). The regex matches `[gallery` + one or more characters other than `[` and `]` up to a whole word `ids="` with `\[gallery[^][]+\bids="`, and then captures into Group 1 all the substring inside double quotes.

With this code, access the first ID via `$ids_arr[0]` and the second ID with  `$ids_arr[1]`.

Here is a way to get all the IDs using one regex operation:

```
$s = '[gallery ids="1955,1947,1951,1945,1953,1949"]';
preg_match_all('~(?:\[gallery[^][]+\bids="|(?!^)\G),?\K\d+~', $s, $ids);
print_r($ids[0]);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IAaEku)

Then you can access the first ID using `$ids[0][0]` and the second via `$ids[0][1]`.

With the pattern, you match one or more digits (having an optional comma before) that are preceded with `\[gallery[^][]+\bids="` (see explanation above) or the end of the previous successful match (with `(?!^)\G)`).

Comment: Please consider accepting if the answer works for you and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.